# multline inside gather?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have 3 related equations, two of them do not fit on a single line.
I want to present them in a gather-environment, but how to do linebreaks inside equations? `multline` does not work inside `gather`.

In isolation, the equations would be typeset as follows:

```
\begin{equation} eq 1 \end{equation} 

\begin{multline} long \\ eq 2 \end{multline}

\begin{multline} long \\ eq 3 \end{multline}
```

Comment: do not use the `equation` environment, use `align` instead, then you can have linebreaks

Answer (score 16):

The `mathtools` package has a `multlined` environment that relates to `multline` as `aligned` to `align`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `split` within `gather`.