# Multline output with multlined inside gather

Tags: mathtools, multline

I have a problem with `multline` inside `gather`.

I already found this old question ([multline inside gather?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/multline-inside-gather)) on the topic, but the answer I got does not really satisfy me.

The problem of using `multlined` inside `gather` is that it is not possible to get the nice effect that we get from `multline`, namely that the second line is shifted toward the right side of the page (at least that's what happens to me).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%%% Multline
\begin{multline*}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multline*}
%
\vspace{-1cm}
%
\begin{multline*}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multline*}



%%% Gather + Multlined
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \\
%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

%%% Gather + Multlined + mathleft
\mathleft
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \\
%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\%
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

From this piece of code it can indeed be noticed that in the first case, when there is `multline`, we obtain this nice effect (the second line is aligned to the left, and in the case of a three line objects, it is centered, with the third left-aligned). On the contrary, this is not the case with `gather`plus `multlined`, even when we add `\mathleft`.

1. Is there a way to obtain this effect with `multlined` inside `gather`?
2. If not, how can I reduce the space between the two `multline` I am writing down?

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you provide a minimal example, that others can copy and test out.

Comment: @daleif: I do not really agree, in the sense that this is not a specific problem of my piece of code, but it is something general. Indeed, the question I linked does not provide a piece of code, for this very reason. Anyway, part of what I got derived from the fact that I was using `mathleft`. Still, the question stands.

Comment: So you want us to do all the work, make all the code, and try to figure out what it is you're asking. Good luck and have a nice weekend.

Comment: Not at all. I am sorry you are taking my feedback in this way, also because I did appreciate your feedback. Still, I didn't agree with it. Just visualize the following situation: if instead of me, a user with nine bronze medal and 87 point, the same question (in this very same format) would have been asked by a superuser, how would you have reacted? If you check my previous questions you see that I usually post codes (and ofter, on my side, I found out from the answers that I was sloppy... shame on me). Just, *on this specific question*,  I did not see the point. Hope I explained my point.

Comment: Talking about sloppiness on my side, I actually linked the wrong question... shame!

Comment: @daleif: I made a search on metatex on why MWE are used so extensively, and I found this (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/are-there-questions-where-we-can-recognize-that-a-mwe-is-not-necessary), which made me see the point of it (indeed, I inserted the MWE). Again, thanks for your feedback, even more so, for having me realize what is the real point of having a MWE.

Comment: See it as the cost of getting help

Comment: However I still do not quite understand what you are trying to do. In any case, I hardly ever use `multline` or `multlined`, I favor `align` and its cousins

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to have – in `gather` - two long (!) equations leftaligned, and divided in such a way that the second line (second and third in the other example) behaves as in `multline`, that is right-aligning (in the other example, centering & left-aligning). Is it possible to get something like this with `align` (I do use it, but I often found its behavior rather mysterious).

Comment: In general I want all the lines aligned or aligned and indented, not centered or right aligned. IMO this gives a better structure on the page. I tend to follow the recommendations from this: ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf#page=57&zoom=auto,-247,771 (section 3.3.5), here `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools` is very handy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! I will take a serious look at it.

Comment: I've had a printed copy of the book for years, just recently noticed it online.

Comment: in looking at the output of the example, i notice that the first two lines are closer together than the rest of the lines, in a `multlined` group of more then two lines.  this happens whether the `multlined` group is within `gather` or `equation`.  this is in addition to the overall width of the `multlined` group, which is definitely narrower than produced by `multline`. (i didn't try anything else.)  i think `multlined` needs to be looked at closely; there seem to be some problems there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both `multline` and `multlined` rely on `\multlinegap` (defined in `amsmath` with
a default value of `10pt`).  however, they use this dimension differently.

for `multline` it is the distance from the margin to the leftmost edge of the
first line or to the rightmost edge of the last line.  if both those lines are
short, there can be a big horizontal gap in the middle of the display.

for `multlined` it is the distance that the first and last lines do *not* overlap.
for this purpose, `10pt` is very tiny, almost not noticeable.

`\multlinegap` can be reset, but it needs to be done with attention to the
environment in which it is to be used.  it must be reset outside the affected
environment.  for `multline`, the effect is global, and must be limited if it is
not to persist; for `multlined`, however, it can be set within the enclosing
display environment, effectively making the change local.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

default \verb+\multlinegap+ (10pt)
\begin{multline*}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multline*}

increase the value of \verb+\multlinegap+ from (default) 10pt to 2cm.
{\multlinegap=2cm
\begin{multline*}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multline*}
}% end of enlarged \multlinegap

%%% Gather + Multlined
default \verb+\multlinegap+ (10pt)
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

increase the value of \verb+\multlinegap+ from (default) 10pt to 2cm.
\begin{gather*}
\multlinegap=2cm
\begin{multlined}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

default \verb+\multlinegap+ (10pt)
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

observe that the first two lines of a `multlined` group are closer together vertically than additional lines in a group of more than two lines.  this appears to be a bug in `multlined` that should be investigated.

**edit:**
here is a further example in which two `multlined` groups are combined into a
single `gather`.  the width of each `multlined` is set to the full `\textwidth` using the option provided by that environment; this width can, of course, be set
to any value desired by the user.  finally, to overcome the uneven vertical
spacing observed in the examples shown above, the space between the second and
third lines of the first `multlined` group is decreased by `\jot`, the unit
used by `amsmath` to control the spacing in multiline structures.  (an effort to determine what is causing the difference in spacing has yielded no useful
information, hence the application of the workaround.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}[\textwidth]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\[-\jot]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}\\
\begin{multlined}[\textwidth]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though, I don't think it actually answer my question, in the sense that it seems to me it deals mainly with vertical spacing, while my issue is on the *horizontal* behavior of the lines (see the very last comment of mine below the question: i.e what I am would like to achieve is to have – in gather - two long (!) equations leftaligned, and divided in such a way that the second line (second and third in the other example) behaves as in multline, that is right-aligning (in the other example, centering & left-aligning)). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Kolmin -- perhaps the further example is closer to what you want.

Comment: Well, super thanks a lot! Actually this is superclose to what I was looking for. I see the point of using `\textwidth`, which pretty much makes the job. At the same time, though, I think this is what makes the result not exactly what I was looking for, in the sense that this command should force the equation to take the entire space given by a line, which is a bit of a stretch (in particular in the example with only two lines), while I would like to get everything left-aligned, but without taking the entire line. Still, this is really superclose, and I have the feeling...

Comment: ... it is not really possible to get closer without messying around heavilty with the code. Again, thanks a lot! :)